# A Mysterious Duel

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I took my place opposite my competitor; and was challenged to a duel...

[image: The Duel]

**What exactly did they challenge me to?**

Comment: For the "green check", you must answer the question, as well as provide reasoning as to how it connects to each of the six images.

Comment: is this a rebus? Maybe a rebus duel? (lol)

Comment: @YoutRied mmmmm...!?

Comment: It's time to d-d-d-d-d-d-duel

Comment: Made a slight change to the story, but that doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @Hugh what does "mmmm" mean? That I'm close or you decided not to put on the rebus tag?

Comment: @YoutRied No comment. (well... you are close-ish but I won't elaborate)

Comment: Pictionary! (lol) Also you commented no comment

Comment: There are… parts of pictures, thats what connects them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have been challenged to a duel of:

> Rock, Paper, Scissors

Picture 1:

> This looks like a picture of a [ROCK Squirell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_squirrel), commonly found in the american southwest.

Picture 2:

> Is a PAPER origami crane.

Picture 3:

> A barber shop pole. Barbers notably use SCISSORS to cut hair.

Picture 4:

> Looks like [himylayan ROCK salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himalayan_salt).

Picture 5:

> Is the [PAPER wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_wasp).

Picture 6:

> Is a snapshot of the traditional Peruvian SCISSOR dance, or the [Danza de tijeras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danza_de_tijeras).

Comment: Well done! You've answered the puzzle perfectly.

Comment: Wait a second... You're trying to tell me that that's not a rot13(png)